# Android Honeycomb Choosing the Right API to Target

Tags: android, api, build, android-3.0-honeycomb, min

Does anyone see a problem targeting api 13 but setting the minSDkVersion to 11?  I want to use the latest and greatest honeycomb api for my tablet app but don't want to exclude any tablets that may be running the earlier version of honeycomb.  Of course I'll test API 11 and 12 using the emulator.

I bring up this question becuase of the warning found in my manifest "Attribute minSdkVersion (11) is lower than the project target API level (13)".

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It means that your project is loaded with version 11 api. 
Right click on project- > properties -> android

Are you using any specific features targetted to version 13? if not, you don't need the targetsdk version.

Comment: Maybe my thoughts about APIs are incorrect.  I figure that even if I'm not using any specific features in version 13 it would be more stable and have less bugs which is why I would choose to use it.  Are later APIs only for new features or do they also fix bugs and make improvements?  ...after thinking about it more, the API is just the interface.  so it only applies to the interface and not improving the source code.  so is it safe to assume that API 11 is just as stable as API 13?